# Given a character of the alphabet I want to compute and print an integer value as a result

Tags: python

Alphabet combines alphabet in lower case and upper case : ab...zAB...Z

If input character is 'a' expected result is 1.

If input character is 'b' expected result is 2.

If input character is 'z' expected result is 26.

If input character is 'A' expected result is 27.

If input character is 'B' expected result is 28.

If input character is 'Z' expected result is 52.

I've tried the above code that works but I wonder if a simplest solution exists.

```py
c = input()
if "a" <= c <= "z":
   print (ord(c)-ord("a")+1)
elif "A" <= c <= "Z":
    print (ord(c)-ord("A")+27)
```

Comment: Are you solving this https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/3 ? :)

Comment: Possible :) I like to find answers and I like even better when code is elegant and to learn how to make it nicer and more readable

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is the place to get feedback for something. Not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ascii_letters` provided by the `string` module *which consists of the lower-case alphabet followed by the upper-case alphabet* and find the index of your letter.

```py
from string import ascii_letters

c = input()
print(ascii_letters.index(c)+1)
```

You could even prepare the "lookup table" with a first unused character, that will avoid to add 1 when calling `index()`.

```py
from string import ascii_letters

table = "." + ascii_letters
c = input()
print(table.index(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `isupper()` and `islower()` methods to check if character is upper or lower

```py
c = input()
if c.islower():
    print(ord(c)-ord('a')+1)
elif c.isupper():
    print(ord(c)-ord('A')+27)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to subtract ord('A') for upper case characters and ord(a) in for lower case ones ?

Comment: @Chris my bad tq